# Redirect Rule For IIS Sharepoint Site

Tags: windows, redirect, iis, sharepoint

We have our Sharepoint 2019 site set up, and everything is running fine. However, when a user clicks the Brand Bar "Sharepoint" in the top left header, it brings them to a broken page. Researched this, and it seems like this link cannot be changed in 2019, as others are having this issue.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ef910ec-fb70-443e-bcf4-2d277dc11d2a/sharepoint-2019-on-premise-management-shell-not-working-as-expected?forum=SP2019

What we wanted to do is a redirect, so whenever they went to the broken link, it would just direct them to the real homepage for our sharepoint.

Example -

Broken link is http://servername/my/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx

Correct link is https://sharepoint.companyname.com/SitePages/Home.aspx

Here is what I came up with to add to the web.config file, but doesnt seem to be working.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
         <add wildcard="*_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx" destination="https://sharepoint.companyname.com/SitePages/Home.aspx" />
      </httpRedirect>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any idea on what needs to be done here? Is this even possible? I didn't set up the sharepoint site here so I'm not sure how http://servername/my/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx even became the brand bar link.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems that your wildcard is incorrect, you can try to change it to sharepoint.aspx and try again. `wildcard="/sharepoint.aspx"`

Comment: So I changed the wildcard section, and still not working as expected. I assume `wildcard=` does not need a actual wildcard to work. I'll remember that for future reference.

Comment: About how to set the wildcard you can refer to this link: [HTTP Redirects <httpRedirect>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/),  or you can try to use iis [url rewrite module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Comment: Thx. I looked into rewrite module as well, wasn't able to get that working either. May just be at a loss here.

Comment: Can you tell me which url you want to redirect to which url? I can use iis url rewrite module to write an example for you as a reference.

Comment: I want to redirect http://servername/my/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx to https://sharepoint.companyname.com/SitePages/Home.aspx

Comment: I post a example below, you can use it as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect from `servername/my/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx` to `sharepoint.companyname.com/SitePages/Home.aspx` by iis url rewrite, you can try this rule.

```
<rule name="test6" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^my/_layouts/15/sharepoint$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://sharepoint.companyname.com/SitePages/Home.aspx" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, so here is where I am at....

After adding the rule, the redirect works on the actual server, going to http://localhost/my/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx it redirects correctly. But, outside of the server, on my local machine, when I go to http://servername/my/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx it does not redirect, and it errors out. I tried clearing cookies in my browser, using different browsers, different computers, none worked. So the rule works perfect, but something about hitting it from outside the server is not working correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error message. I have tracing on for failed requests and nothing is getting logged when I hit it from outside the server, only from inside the server.

Also, yesterday I enabled proxy on Application Request Routing., and didnt work. Going to keep digging into it today.

Comment: how do you know that it has gone wrong? there is no error message, it is difficult for me to help you solve the problem, you can check whether there are related error messages in the event viewer.

Comment: So something new I found yesterday....when I go to http://servername/my/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx it fails to redirect. But, when I go to https://servername/my/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx it redirects as expected. So looks like this is now a http to https rewrite that I am working on to use before the other rewrite rule.

Comment: Your two URL are the same,does http to https work? https to http doesn’t work?

Comment: Apologize for that, forgot they wont show up.

when I go to HTTPS of the my_layouts page, it redirects fine. But when I go to HTTP of the my_layouts page, it gives a 404.

The issue is that when you click the brand banner "Sharepoint" on the top, it brings you to the HTTP site, which doesnt redirect and errors out. was trying to redirect HTTP to HTTPS and no dice so far.

Below comment is my current rule.

Comment: <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" negate="true" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>      
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^my/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx$" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://sharepoint.servername.com/SitePages/Home.aspx" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

Comment: Try to add the following rules to see if there are any errors. <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{RequiresSSL:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" negate="true" />
 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.+)\.(?!aspx)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
 </rule>

Comment: Wouldnt that just redirect any HTTPS traffic to use HTTP? We need the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved.

Not sure what happened, only thing I did was place the rule on the top most part of the tree in IIS where the server name is. Before I was putting the rule on the actual site in the drop down. I guess this makes sense since the URL I wanted to redirect had the server name in it.